# Linking Local MongoDB Data to Dockerized MongoDB container

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am new to `docker` and I'm trying to hookup my dockerized `mongodb` to my local and former data directory located in `/data/db` and then I saw [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/68) that `The host machine volume directory cannot be under /Users (or ~).` So, I moved my previous `/data/db` to `/Users/ComputerName/Docker/Mongo/data/db` and `chown` the directory to `ComputerName` and changed the permission to `777` and then ran

`docker run -p 27017:27017 -v /Users/ComputerName/Docker/Mongo/data/db:/data/db --name mongo -d mongo mongod --smallfiles` and I'm still getting this error below:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/_mdb_catalog.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-0--2573889005034950089.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-0-172311321946494465.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-0-5057819112596801042.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-0-7557672013303810902.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-0-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-10-5057819112596801042.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-11-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-13-5057819112596801042.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-13-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-1437-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-1439-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-1441-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-1443-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-1446-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-1450-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-1452-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-1454-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-1456-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-1459-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-15-5057819112596801042.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-15-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-17-5057819112596801042.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-19-5057819112596801042.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-19-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-2-5057819112596801042.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-2-8264987329754823755.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-2059-8691005967059534031.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-2061-8691005967059534031.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-2063-8691005967059534031.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-2066-8691005967059534031.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-2068-8691005967059534031.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-2070-8691005967059534031.wt': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db/collection-2072-8691005967059534031.wt': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: I'm a little confused.   Granted I know nothing of OSX, however the issue you linked says "No Data in /Users" and your question is Why doesn't my data work in /Users

Comment: Yeah. But, not totally the same. And my question is why do I get this errors and how can I allow the `Dockerized MongoDB` to access my previous DB data? And also to only save to utilize that existing dat @user2105103

Comment: I guess I'm still confused.   No matter what it is called -inside- the container.   It's still at /Users outside -- and apparently boot2docker no likey.   Have you tried moving it to /var/lib or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you changed chmod with -R modifier? You can also try to add Yours account name to docker group.
- usermod -a -G docker

Comment: Thanks. I didn't run the `chmod` recursively.